# Capturing transactions opened / committed during backup

Tags: postgresql, backup

I gotta believe there's a way to do this, but not clear how. Don't know PostgreSQL internals well enough, however.

Let's say I start a dump of a database at 11:00, and I know said dump takes 5 minutes to complete.

1. I have an open transaction (T1) that was created at 10:59 and because [some reason] it doesn't COMMIT till 11:03
2. A new transaction (T2) is opened and committed at 11:01
3. Another transaction (T3) is created at 11:03 and COMMITs at 11:04

Is there a relatively straight-forward way to capture T1-T3 and include them in the same archive as all of the other committed changes that occurred between the time of my last backup and 11:00? In essence, I want to "loop back" to capture all the activity that occurred between 11-11:05 and save that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a `pg_dump` captures the point in time when it started.

You seem to want point-in-time-recovery, for which you need `pg_basebackup` and WAL archives.